# Gatsby contentful fluid image stretched over 100%

Tags: gatsby, fluid, gatsby-image, stretched

I'm trying to fill a div with array of images using

```
fluid{
       ...GatsbyContentfulFluid             
      }
```

everything works fine except that gatsby stretches images smaller than a div width to fill out whole space (which he suppose to) but my question is if I can prevent this and for those images use 100% of their width without stretching them and only apply fluid to bigger images.

[gatsby-image plugin says that I can use GatsbyImageSharpFluidLimitPresentationSize fragment](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/#avoiding-stretched-images-using-the-fluid-type)

but this does not work with contentful

Is there an easy fix? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a few trials to bypass it based on your requirements:

- As you said, Contentful doesn't allow `GatsbyImageSharpFluidLimitPresentationSize` fragment, however, you can download the asset with the `downloadLocal: true` [plugin option](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#download-assets-for-static-distribution), and apply a `staticQuery` with the `GatsbyImageSharpFluidLimitPresentationSize` fragment. I would look something like:

  ```
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
      query {
        file(relativePath: { eq: "path/to/image/default.jpg" }) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluidLimitPresentationSize
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `)

    return <Img fixed={data.file.childImageSharp.fixed} />
  }
  ```
- Another option, which may require more treatment (mediaqueries and CSS effort) is to use one of the fixed-size fragments that are [allowed by Contentful](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/#gatsby-source-contentful).